# Extract part of XML files in a folder

Tags: python, xml, annotations, object-detection

I have a folder with a number of Pascal Voc XML annotations of images. The annotations looks like the one in below

```
<annotation>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <filename>Norway_000000.jpg</filename>
    <size>
        <width>3650</width>
        <height>2044</height>
        <depth/>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>D00</name>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1138.46</xmin>
            <ymin>1281.93</ymin>
            <xmax>1169.35</xmax>
            <ymax>1336.85</ymax>
        </bndbox>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>rotation</name>
                <value>0.0</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>D20</name>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1537.53</xmin>
            <ymin>1131.79</ymin>
            <xmax>1629.06</xmax>
            <ymax>1247.64</ymax>
        </bndbox>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>rotation</name>
                <value>0.0</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>D00</name>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1773.45</xmin>
            <ymin>1825.97</ymin>
            <xmax>1862.69</xmax>
            <ymax>2038.78</ymax>
        </bndbox>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>rotation</name>
                <value>0.0</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>D00</name>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1589.02</xmin>
            <ymin>1296.26</ymin>
            <xmax>1624.77</xmax>
            <ymax>1343.46</ymax>
        </bndbox>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>rotation</name>
                <value>0.0</value>
            </attribute>
            </attributes>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>D00</name>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1507.53</xmin>
            <ymin>1216.53</ymin>
            <xmax>1527.49</xmax>
            <ymax>1254.27</ymax>
        </bndbox>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>rotation</name>
                <value>0.0</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I want to extract only the following part and save the new xml file.

```
<object>
    <name>D00</name>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <occluded>0</occluded>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>1138.46</xmin>
        <ymin>1281.93</ymin>
        <xmax>1169.35</xmax>
        <ymax>1336.85</ymax>
    </bndbox>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <name>rotation</name>
            <value>0.0</value>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</object>
```

I did not find any specific resource or guide to solve this except for manual removal of the unwanted parts. How can I read all the files in the folder, extract only the desired annotation and then save the new xml files? I need the images for custom object detection in tensorflow.

Comment: What is the criterion for extracting that particular `object` element from the original XML?

Comment: I am sorry I do not get what you meant by criterion.

Comment: There are 5 `object` elements in the original XML, How do you know which one to extract?

Comment: Okay. For example, the main xml has 5 objects with 2 types; D00 and D20. I need all of the objects that has the name D00 in the main xml file.

Comment: In the question you say "I want to extract only the following part". Now you say "all of the objects". Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I wanted to mean one type of object. If it has repeatation, then all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way how you can extract each `objects`.
You can later on simply `iterate` inside them and search for certain `name`.

This is a part where I try to find all `object` elements:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = ET.parse('YourXml.xml')
xml_root = xml_file.getroot()
xml_objects = list()

for i in xml_root:
    if i.tag == 'object':
        xml_objects.append(i)
```

In this part I convert `Elements` to `ElementTree` which lets me to `write` them to **.xml** file.

```
for iter_i, i in enumerate(xml_objects):
   ET.ElementTree(i).write(f'D:\\object_{iter_i}.xml')
```

Comment: tried couple of times, but did not work.

Comment: It did for me. There has to be some mistake on your side. @Tahmid